# Type narrowing when assigning an object's property from another same-type object's same property

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a small function to merge two same-type object into a third same-type object but I'm having trouble with the typings.

Here's an example of my situation (also on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgCbAG7AwVzgBsARMAe2QG8AoZZGYKAZzBDgFsJmAuZVqKADmAbQC6AbjrIARkzAALDHEi9kJFRHFSAvjRox8IBGGDkQyLlCER0WXAWLMAFNPqh7eQkQCMfOzhexGTkADRuyB6BjkQATP6Y0d4h0gCUCZ4xIdQRCOasltA2GAEO3hlJwRTIALzUDEys7Fxq4qGy8kqarWI6UvT0eSAFcFBQcACeAApQ5AAO0KbctcgiEfQARIwsbJzcG+EDAxtyUIrKqgcRYshwzMhDrFIRo+PTswtnwNwAdDDkUAAoogFM5nHMPosJqlagA+HJHehWYqlIJEEQQ+ZQm51EQ-fFRMrEHwYyFnCZidr4n6EtGxUlY8liSQRHSpZ5HKAQMD4KAWZEQEqJIlEfrIHRAA)):

```
interface IndividualDto {
  firstnames: string[];
  birthdates: Date[];
}

function mergeIndividuals(
    individual1: IndividualDto,
    individual2: IndividualDto
  ): IndividualDto {
    const mergedIndividual: IndividualDto = { firstnames: [], birthdates: []};
    const arrayProperties = [
      "firstnames",
      "birthdates",
    ] as const;

    arrayProperties.forEach((property) => {
      mergedIndividual[property] = [...individual1[property], ...individual2[property]];
    });

    return mergedIndividual;
  }
```

My idea is to treat all of those property the same way and deal with other properties in another way (not relevent here.)

With this code I have the following error on `mergedIndividual[property]`, though:

```
Type '(string | MilDate)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] & MilDate[]'.
  Type '(string | MilDate)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
    Type 'string | MilDate' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'MilDate' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

TypeScript doesn't seem to be able to understand that because the three objects are of the same type and I'm referencing the same property, they're all compatible for assignment.

Also, I would like to explicitly type `arrayProperties` so that I cannot add strings which are not keys of `IndividualDto`. I've tried using `const arrayProperties: readonly (keyof IndividualDto)[]` but it's less specific than the string union and creates other errors related to other properties not being array types.

Comment: *"Also, I would like to explicitly type arrayProperties so that I cannot add strings which are not keys of IndividualDto. I've tried using const arrayProperties: readonly (keyof IndividualDto)[] but it's less specific than the string union and creates other errors related to other properties not being array types."* That's odd, I don't have that problem ([example](https://tsplay.dev/wR53QW)).

Comment: You're right @T.J.Crowder, I should have provided a playground! Sorry! I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript doesn't know **which** property `property` names, just that it's one of the properties of `IndividualDto` (if you type the array correctly). So `mergedIndividual[property]` ends up with the type`string[] & MilDate[]`, which of course you can't assign anything to.

You could split `IndividualDto` into two interfaces (which you can then combine into a single `IndividualDto` type) where the types of all of the properties are the same. For instance:

```typescript
// The properties that are `string[]`
interface IndividualDtoStringArrays {
    firstnames: string[];
    lastnames: string[];
}

// The properties that are `MilDate[]`
interface IndividualDtoMilDateArrays {
    birthDates: MilDate[];
}

// The overall type
type IndividualDto = IndividualDtoStringArrays & IndividualDtoMilDateArrays;
```

That way, you can use two separate arrays and TypeScript is happy because there's no type ambiguity:

```typescript
function mergeIndividuals(
    individual1: IndividualDto,
    individual2: IndividualDto
): IndividualDto {
    const mergedIndividual = emptyIndividualDto();
    const stringArrayProperties: readonly (keyof IndividualDtoStringArrays)[] = [
        "firstnames",
        "lastnames",
        // ...
    ];
    const milDateArrayProperties: readonly (keyof IndividualDtoMilDateArrays)[] = [
        "birthDates",
        // ...
    ];

    for (const property of stringArrayProperties) {
        mergedIndividual[property] = [...individual1[property], ...individual2[property]];
    }
    for (const property of milDateArrayProperties) {
        mergedIndividual[property] = [...individual1[property], ...individual2[property]];
    }

    return mergedIndividual;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsglgGwCIENjQLxVeg3AKHwHoioAVAC2jACcB7SG4OCAZymArShRugANWwGnAB2AcwDaAXX74x6GgDMUAY2gBJUQBM4ANzjaArimTA6AZWFjxAQRo0UIdgG98UD1CVwaQ0SgBbNgAuKCERCRkCTygEFD9AkLDrSOkCAF9CEnIqKFoGCCYWdk5uXgF4ZDQIGTkFQpV1KC1dA2NTJHNKnAh7R2coNxiAIx9OHtZQ7uqo-EziUkpoOj1C0wQOcAh8UEhmnX1DEzM6KCwWw-aTqwi7Byd2ADJ91qOOrsQevoeCfCUjUSqZh0URQCABMCgC5tY6dOgACgAlKFoW8ToN3J4+MAjDRQUMYp5vL5gP4gpMoDIADSYwmxeKkxIU6m0wmjJgUCahFkxdIZP4AoFwEFQII0cQQVFXVjw1liV5XACMKIOMPedBpMXll2OACYVQrYeZ8MiXjr1RiYqoQUJRYUJdopcczmCIVDVWi4Ujop5raJbeEbN8QAAFeiMZhJPgobQghAgKDwgDWEBAdCUZrV1xSd36rERMhdklZMQARMSEuTS5q6VBS3FK2xq6y0qy-baAp9qsGwwUilGIDG4wnk6n05nPR8quhg-nC1hi7W6+zxtVWM2Yq3WUo6DRE+3gHlw4VQFBx4GJD3j-385ba2KHU7TJJ8hGQNIiwA6b-arOKl-XqA0hUlA36fr+aK6gBfZAa2vLbru+42oer4ngm46dtOvT3KGgHFIid50g+ECOh6VzQW+H4LmBEFKhRaHAaBP5kXq9FMO+cGePMMTYrioLEaRhqmPyQA)

---

Alternatively: This is a small, well-contained utility function, and even though TypeScript doesn't know the assignment is valid, **you** do. So you might just go for error suppression via `ts-ignore`:

```typescript
function mergeIndividuals(
    individual1: IndividualDto,
    individual2: IndividualDto
): IndividualDto {
    const mergedIndividual = emptyIndividualDto();
    const arrayProperties: readonly (keyof IndividualDto)[] = [
        "firstnames",
        "lastnames",
        "birthDates",
    ];

    for (const property of arrayProperties) {
        // @ts-ignore
        mergedIndividual[property] = [...individual1[property], ...individual2[property]];
    }

    return mergedIndividual;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsglgGwCIENjQLxVeg3AKHzgDt0AnAMxQGNoBJYgEzgDc5GBXFZYAeygDe+KCKgU4ZAM7BiKALYRJALijSyJAOYBtALoFRUBCmmyFy1cHXFte4aIBGE4AAscilfGRoIuggF9CCg5iamA4XmIoCDkwUAZmNk5uJD4ACgBKFXjWdi4efiEDMghgDjJIwoNRcSkZeXcoXQAaOyrDYzqzFWbWqscyFzdzHoM-f3wgkLCIqAUyDQhsxLzJVN6SBNzuAEYsphyk-JaDDYO8gCY9zcOU3nxMqCWt-MFe6gjpWYh5iEYnw6gWGisRA-zytwy+lE72InxQZDIKBAAAUyLxIAM4A1iihGBEECAoKkANYQEC8CiPfbLZJ8dK6QGNXoGABENRM9UkLOObSgLKMHLM3OZohZ-UG3i5PJEtl6FF4ZCJMM+YDRGNAUApUHhiJRau+YUU6VevKgAHozVAAALASQAWjgGmICogIpEcwWf2pzy0qvRBpAOkZWgAdGHTjSENtffqBoGmlAwyGI89zjH-XGdLZRoQiiUypEPb8wdxxkA)

**Error suppression, like type assertion, is best avoided.** Your object looks like it just has a couple of types of properties, so I'd probably go with the first solution (separate loops). But this is a viable option in a small, well-contained function like this one.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! But can't TypeScript, in that situation, be a bit smarter?

Comment: @Jeahel - Not that I'm aware of, but I'm still at the journeyman level with it.